# json data return in other function

Tags: jquery, json

i have this function and when i use alert it gives me required data but i want to use this data inside other function and when i call this function inside that function using console.log i get undefined

```
function huuu() {
    var siteoriginn ='https://xttttz.com/';
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: siteoriginn + "datafile.php,
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(e) {

                ! function(e, t) {
                    try {
                        sessionStorage.setItem(e, t)
                    } catch (e) {
                        return
                    }
                }         

  //    it alerts the data in json format but i want to call this data in other function
//  alert(JSON.stringify(e)); 
       JSON.stringify(e);

        }

        })
    }
```

i call this inside another function with

```
                    console.log(huuu());
```

which gives undefined. what mistake i am doing ??

any help will be great

Comment: Apart from ajax being **asynchronous** you don't have any `return` in `huuu()` either

Comment: @charlietfl i tried return like this  return JSON.stringify(e); but did not work

Comment: Did you ***thoroughly*** read the duplicate I linked to and review all the various solutions?

Comment: @charlietfl i am checking now